# Visa queries from an Indian planning a Machu Picchu, Peru vacation

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, peru

I am in US currently and an Indian citizen.

What's visa process and is it easy to get one?

Do we get multiple entry or single entry visa?

Do I need to have itinerary and tickets first before I get visa or can I do all that once I get visa?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an Indian national, you will require a visa to visit Peru. According to the [Consulate of Peru in San Francisco](http://www.consuladoperu.com/general/index.php?consulado=SAN%20FRANCISCO&pagina=RequisitosVisa.php), the requirements are:

> **Tourist Visa**
>
> - Fill out the obligatory visa application form.
> - Personal interview.
> - Valid passport. According to the normative 3.11  of  the International Civil Aviation Organization (OACI), handwritten passport are only valid  if they were issue after November 24th 2005 and expired before November 24th 2015 .
> - Proof of legal residence in the USA: Green Card; or american visa (NOT tourist visa)
> - Round trip ticket (Can be reservation or an electronic booking confirmation).
> - Hotel reservation, Tourist package reservation, or Invitation letter (legalized by the Ministry of Foreign Affairs of Peru).
> - One (1) passport photo.
> - Proof of sufficient funds during stay in Perú : Copy of a recent bank statement.
> - Application fee is $ 30.00, cash or money order payable to « Consulate of Peru ».
>
> **** The presentation of a Visa application does not guarantee the issuance of a visa. Each application is individually evaluated by a Peruvian consular officer.***

So you need travel tickets and a hotel booking before applying for the visa.

Answer (score 2):

As of March 2017, any Indian national with a valid visa from United States, Canada, the United Kingdom, Australia or any Schengen State, can visit Perú without a visa [[1](http://www.andina.com.pe/ingles/noticia-peru-govt-waives-visa-for-indian-citizens-656746.aspx)][[2](http://busquedas.elperuano.com.pe/normaslegales/exoneran-del-requisito-de-visa-temporal-en-las-calidades-mig-decreto-supremo-n-006-2017-re-1493143-11/)].

I visited the country last month. Both me and my wife have a Canadian tourist and US work visa, immigration officer checked my US visa and my wife's Canadian visa.